EFS metadata IOPS surges
I have a wordpress server using a mounted EFS disk. I have noticed that my EFS sometimes goes through long periods (hours, sometimes days) of high metadata IOPS. So much so that when this disk was bursting, then this would consume my burst credits very quickly. I have had to change to expensive Elastic FS type to prevent this.

I am relatively sure this is not any process that I am in control of. What exactly is a metadata IOPS and can I prevent it running for so long on my EFS?

Metadata IOPS are when something on your server is just listing all files on a disk, or checking file sizes. Basically any file operation other than reading the actual contents of the files. It is definitely being generated by some process on your WordPress server. I've seen some WordPress plugins generate a ton of EFS metadata IOPS, and it can be extremely difficult to figure out which one is causing it.
